# Excel Deletes Decimal Numbers

Tags: mysql, excel

I'm working with excel to analysis some data from a database. I get the data via ODBC driver from a MySQL database. There are some Cols with time values. No Problem so far. My cellformat is:

```
hh:mm:ss,000
```

Appliying the format is no problem, I refresh the cells with a macro which applies the "text to column" function from excel (The same effect would be mark a whole col and hitting enter, it reenters the value and applies the format). Now My Problem- if I hit this function a second time or just hit manual enter, it deletes the decimal digits, have a look:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Has anyone a Idea?

Comment: Any interest in alternative code??

Comment: sure, alternative code for what? for that "refresh"?

Comment: Well using `TextToColumns` works great if the source is Text.  If the source is a formatted number, then `TextToColumns` may not work properly.  Running you macro twice may not work.

Comment: yes exaclty. do you have an alternative?

Comment: Check back in a bit

Comment: all right! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumes that are are using the US locale *(that the decimal point* . *is the decimal separator).*

Say we have a column of *Text* values like:

[image]

The following macro will convert them into true Excel times with format *"hh:mm:ss.000"*

In the US locale, this format *"hh:mm:ss,000"* is not legal:

```
Sub fixData()
    Dim r As Range, s As String
    Dim hrs As Long, mins As Long, secs As Long
    Dim milli As Long, d As Double

    Selection.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss.000"

    For Each r In Selection
        s = r.Text
        milli = CLng(Right(s, 3))
        hrs = CLng(Left(s, 2))
        mins = CLng(Mid(s, 4, 2))
        secs = CLng(Mid(s, 7, 2))
        d = hrs / (24#) + mins / (24# * 60) + secs / (24# * 60 * 60) + milli / (24# * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        r.Value = d
    Next r
End Sub
```

Afterwards:

[image]

Note that after processing, the Formula Bar does **not** display the milli-seconds, although it is there.

Comment: @chris000r Once the conversion has been performed, you can edit the data.